# Login failure without clear error specification

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to authenticate my application, and it fails to login. I saw that it always redirect to login again even if the credentials(username and password are ok).

in my user.rb I have :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :nome, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

  validates :password, :confirmation => true
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation
  attr_reader   :password

  validate  :password_must_be_present


   def User.authenticate(nome, password)
    if user = find_by_nome(nome)
      if user.hashed_password == encrypt_password(password, user.salt)
        user
      end
    end
  end

  def User.encrypt_password(password, salt)
    Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(password + "wibble" + salt)
  end

  # 'password' is a virtual attribute
  def password=(password)
    @password = password

    if password.present?
      generate_salt
      self.hashed_password = self.class.encrypt_password(password, salt)
    end
  end

  private

    def password_must_be_present
      errors.add(:password, "Missing password") unless hashed_password.present?
    end

    def generate_salt
      self.salt = self.object_id.to_s + rand.to_s
    end

     attr_accessible :hashed_password, :nome, :salt
end
```

In my user_controller I have:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.xml
  def index
    @users = User.order(:nome)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.xml
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.xml
  def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.xml
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to(users_url,
          :notice => "Usuario #{@user.nome} criado com sucesso") }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user,
          :status => :created, :location => @user }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors,
          :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.xml
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to(users_url,
          :notice => "Usuario #{@user.nome} actualizado com sucesso.") }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors,
          :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.xml
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(users_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

In my session_controller I have:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
 skip_before_filter :authorize
  def new
  end

  def create
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:nome], params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to admin_url
    else
      redirect_to login_url, :alert => "Nome do usuario/password invalido"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to store_url, :notice => "Logged out"
  end
end
```

In my _form I have:

```
<div class="mapira_form" >
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation" >
<h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>
prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
<ul>
<% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
<li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<fieldset>
<legend>Entrar detalhes do usuarioo</legend>
<div>
<%= f.label :nome %>:
<%= f.text_field :nome, :size => 40 %>
</div>
<div>
<%= f.label :password, 'Password' %>:
<%= f.password_field :password, :size => 40 %>
</div>
<div>
<%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirmar password' %>:
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :size => 40 %>
</div>
<div>
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
</div>
```

And my server is responding in this way:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.9 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
        SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
        This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
        provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
        cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
        future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

        Called from: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `ini
tialize'.

>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop


Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-13 10:37:16 +0200
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"1a785Bi1Q0DqLq6kdCS7ieP1HJ4Aqh3yLg51rRte31Y=", "nome"=>"prombas", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"
, "commit"=>"Login"}
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."nome" = 'prombas' LIMIT 1←[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
Completed 302 Found in 136ms (ActiveRecord: 11.0ms)


Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-13 10:37:18 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (10.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 53ms (Views: 53.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-13 10:37:19 +0200
Served asset /logo.png - 304 Not Modified (5ms)
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: check whether cookies are enabled or not...

Comment: @Thaha kp they were enabled. I've tried to disable, it hides error message on the browser, and still continue failing to login.

Answer (score 0):

The encryption method is case-sensitive.  Try forcing password to either upcase or downcase on both the setting of hashed_password and in authenticate.

Comment: Still continue with the same failure.

Comment: Did you try using debug to see that the authenticate method in User is working properly?

Comment: Yes I did, and I got the following error :  Started GET "/assets/users.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-12 18:17:43 +0200
Served asset /users.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
[2013-08-12 18:17:43] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked =
 true. I'M NOW USING 'thin' AS A SUGGESTION I FOUND TO SOLVE THAT PROBLEM, BUT I CAN'T LOGIN ALSO.

Comment: So you are sure that 'user' is being correctly returned from User.authenticate?  In which case what is the controller that admin_url is mapped to?  And what is the content of the authorize method?

Comment: Yes, it sends the parameters and retrieves the user, and the admin_url redirects to StoreController#index.

Comment: This suggests that the authorize method, (which SessionController skips), thinks the user is not logged in.  Can you post the content of this method please?  Or you might need to debug to check that the user is actually in the session at that point.  What type of session store are you using?